# Asymptotic complexity between 2 functions

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

Hello this is my first question here,
It's about the running time.

We have 2 functions:

**f(n) = n!**

**g(n) = log(n)^(n+1)**

I'm having trouble understanding the relation between them

Is `f(n) = θ(g(n))`?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think there is a relation between them?

Answer (score 0):

Frist, you can take a `log` from both functions, like the following:

```
log(f(n)) = log(n!) = Theta(n log(n))
log(g(n)) = log(log(n)^(n+1)) = (n+1) log(log(n))
```

Hence, `log(g(n))` is in `o(log(f(n)))` (little-oh). Therefore, we can say `e^(log(g(n))) = g(n)` is in `o(e^(log(f(n))) = o(f(n))`.

Comment: I'm not convinced about the conclusion in "Therefore". Can you justify that you can simply insert `e^` like that?